# How to configure JNDI data source for liquibase task by using springboot and tomcat server resource database?

Tags: apache, spring-boot, jndi, tomcat8, liquibase

I'm working on Spring boot Application along with liquibase version 3.5.3, in which I need to configure two different JNDI data source for liquibase task and application execution.
I  have created two different JNDI data source in tomcat server.xml file

```
<Resource name="JDBC/DSAdmin"
         global="jdbc/DSAdmin"
         auth="Container"
         factory="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory"
         type="javax.sql.DataSource"
         driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname"
         username="admin"
         password="admin"
         minimumIdle="5" maximumPoolSize="50" connectionTimeout="300000" maxLifetime="1800000" />
and 
<Resource name="jdbc/DS"
         global="jdbc/DS"
         auth="Container"
         factory="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory"
         type="javax.sql.DataSource"
         driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database"
         username="root"
         password="root"
         minimumIdle="5" maximumPoolSize="50" connectionTimeout="300000" maxLifetime="1800000" />
```

I need to run the liquibase task using the jdbc/DSAdmin connection pool and application using the jdbc/DS connection pool.

But liquibase version 3.5.3 doesn't provide any property to specify data source by using tomcat server resource.

In application.properties file, I have configured `spring.datasource.jndi-name = java:comp/env/jdbc/DSAdmin`

Similarly I want to configure `liquibase.datasoure=java:comp/env/jdbc/DS`

this is my context.xml file

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/DS" 
     global="jdbc/DS"
     auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource" /> 

<ResourceLink name="jdbc/DSAdmin" 
     global="jdbc/DSAdmin"
     auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```